# Compile error when trying to import web3.swift

Tags: web3js, ether

I am trying to import web3swift into one of my Swift files, but get the compiler error "No such module 'web3swift'". The import statements look like this:

"Import Geth"
"Import web3swift"

In my pod file, I have:

`pod 'web3swift', :git => 'https://github.com/MercuryProtocol/web3.swift.git', :branch => 'master'`

I have also tried the following fix which hasn't worked:
=> In case you get no such module web3swift error
Go to “Build Settings”
Search “Framework Search Paths” (case sensitive)
Double click on 
Click the “+”
Add $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive

Comment: Do you need any help with that? it should work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

See this blog, In this blog, I have generated wallet as well as a transaction in Ether and ERC20 token.

https://medium.com/@shivangpandey195/getting-started-with-web3swift-1a2454481f70

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are importing MercuryProtocol repo: `Web3.swift`.
And try to import Materinc implementation: `web3swift`

I recommend you to use this line in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'web3swift'
```

https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift library is well supported and do all interactions natively without 3-rd party integration (like Geth in MercuryProtocol).